# Case statement between two columns in two tables

Tags: mysql

Im trying to write a case statement (Or use any statement)in MySQL that will print out a value if the variable = true. 
Basically, in my select statement, if the value in one table is 10, then display a value within a new column

I was thinking to use something like this:

`CASE (table1.payment WHEN 10 THEN table2.type END) AS plan`

The above does not work and has syntax errors. What can I do to achieve my desired results?

Comment: You are missing the `END` keyword at the end of your expression: `CASE (table1.payment WHEN 10 THEN table2.type END) AS plan`

Comment: `CASE ... END` is an *expression*, not a *statement*. An expression can be used in the context of a statement, for example, a `SELECT` statement. Attempting to execute a `CASE` expression as a SQL statement is going to cause a syntax error.  Try something like `SELECT CASE table1.payment WHEN 10 THEN table2.type ELSE NULL END AS plan FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ...`

Answer (score 0):

In your case I think it is optimal to use IF, because it is one option to check (it is 10 or not) and IF is faster for such a check.

```
IF(table1.payment=10,table2.type,table1.payment) AS plan
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp For more information.

Option using case looks like:

```
(CASE
WHEN table1.payment=10 THEN table2.type
ELSE table1.payment
END) AS plan
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp For more information.

Execution time comparison for **ONE** check IF and CASE queries:

*Bigger result*

[image: Bigger query]

*Smaller result*

[image: Smaller query]

Comment: While I accept the general precept that a case is faster than multiple ifs, it's not obvious that an if is faster than a single case. Do you have any evidence to support this assertion?

Comment: Added evidences to the answer.